Issue with Sending .dotx Files from Server to Client in C# - Data Loss During Transmission
I have loaded a file in Azure Blob Storage and now I am trying to download it.
I set up a button that triggers the following code:
protected async void WebPagePopupDownloadDocumentButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string rawJson = JsonResultHiddenField.Value;

            string unescapedJson = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rawJson).Trim('"');

            if (unescapedJson.StartsWith("\"") && unescapedJson.EndsWith("\""))
            {
                unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Substring(1, unescapedJson.Length - 2);
            }

            unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Replace("\\\"", "\"");

            unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Replace("\\r", "").Replace("\\n", "");

            try
            {
                var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(unescapedJson);
                string fileUrl = (string)jsonObject["Documents"]?[0]?["FileUrl"];
                if (fileUrl != null)
                {
                    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        string guidText = GuidLabel.Text;
                        string guid = guidText.Substring(guidText.IndexOf(":") + 2).Trim();
                        var configManager = Container.Resolve<IFeConfigManager>();
                        var nawServicesUrl = configManager.GetModel<KeyValueConfig>(ConfigurationModels.SendToInfolex, ApplicationManager.Instance.RecoverProductId())["NawServicesUrl"];

                        var accessToken = SessionManager.Instance.RecoverSession()?.OidcWorkflowData?.TokenResponseData?.AccessToken;
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);
                        string url = $"{nawServicesUrl}{DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENT_OP}?guid={guid}&fileName={fileName}";

                        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        var fileBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                        string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, fileBytes);

                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.ContentType = GetContentType(fileName);
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");
                        Response.TransmitFile(tempFilePath);
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No FileUrl found.");
                }
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"JSON parse error: {ex.Message}");

            }

        }

        private string GetContentType(string fileName)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".pdf":
                    return "application/pdf";
                case ".doc":
                    return "application/msword";
                case ".docx":
                    return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                case ".html":
                    return "text/html";
                case ".dotx":
                    return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template";
                default:
                    return "application/octet-stream";

            }

With this code, I invoke the service that communicates with the Blob Storage to get the file. I can now download any file (HTML, PDF, DOCX, DOTX...) but I can only open html and pdf files correctly. If I try to open .docx files, I get the following pop-up from Microsoft Word:

Which basically says that some unreadable content was found and is asking if I am sure about retrieving the content. If I select "Yes", it opens without further problems.
If I try to open the DOTX file, I get the following message:

and it just simply does not let me open it.
I tried to download the file directly from my Azure Blob Storage, and it works perfectly fine. Furthermore, if I compare both files, I can see different sizes:

The one with the higher amount of KB is the one I downloaded directly from Azure Blob Storage and It can be opened without any problem. The other is the one I downloaded clicking my button in my application.
Using HxD I saw that the last 10KB are the ones missing.
I saw on the Internet that, as a recomendation, it would be best to download the file first ON the server (using a temporal path for example) and then transfer this file through http to the client. This is what I am showing in the first piece of code I included above, but it is not working.
I also checked if the file downloaded in the temporary path had the same size that the one I sent back to the client and it does.
As an alternative, I tried to directly transfer the bytes:
var fileBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();  
Response.Clear(); 
Response.ContentType = GetContentType(fileName); 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}"); Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes); Response.End();     

and writing the data asynchronously:
var fileBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
await WriteBytesAsync(tempFilePath, fileBytes);

...

private async Task WriteBytesAsync(string filePath, byte[] bytes)
 {
     using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
     {
         await fileStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     }
}

but nothing works.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162823/readasbytearrayasync-returns-unreadable

@HansPassant Even though my problem was not about the file being in gzip format or whatever, I tried to set accept header to httpclient and it did not work. In any case, every post I have seen about the topic shows the Response with headers set up, ContentType and then using Response.End() (or simply using Response.Flush() and CompleteRequest()) to end the transmission

Apparently, the problem was the asynchronism of the method. Once I changed it to synchronous, it started to work with DOCX and DOTX files without any problems.
I just had to adapt the method to work in a synchronous way.
protected void WebPagePopupDownloadDocumentButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rawJson = JsonResultHiddenField.Value;
 
    string unescapedJson = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rawJson).Trim('"');
 
    if (unescapedJson.StartsWith("\"") && unescapedJson.EndsWith("\""))
    {
        unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Substring(1, unescapedJson.Length - 2);
    }
 
    // Reemplazar comillas escapadas por comillas normales
    unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
 
    // Reemplazar secuencias de escape de nueva línea y retorno de carro
    unescapedJson = unescapedJson.Replace("\\r", "").Replace("\\n", "");
 
    try
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(unescapedJson);
        string fileUrl = (string)jsonObject["Documents"]?[0]?["FileUrl"];
        if (fileUrl != null)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string guidText = GuidLabel.Text;
                string guid = guidText.Substring(guidText.IndexOf(":") + 2).Trim();
                var configManager = Container.Resolve<IFeConfigManager>();
                var nawServicesUrl = configManager.GetModel<KeyValueConfig>(ConfigurationModels.SendToInfolex, ApplicationManager.Instance.RecoverProductId())["NawServicesUrl"];
 
                var accessToken = SessionManager.Instance.RecoverSession()?.OidcWorkflowData?.TokenResponseData?.AccessToken;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
 
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);
                string url = $"{nawServicesUrl}{DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENT_OP}?guid={guid}&fileName={fileName}";
 
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 
                var fileBytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
 
                byte[] responded = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\documentos\\LE0000309959_20030101.docx");
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = GetContentType("C:\\documentos\\LE0000309959_20030101.docx");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=LE0000309959_20030101.docx");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", responded.Length.ToString());
 
                // Escribir los bytes del archivo en la respuesta
 
                Response.OutputStream.Write(responded, 0, responded.Length);
                Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                Response.End();
 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No FileUrl found.");
        }
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"JSON parse error: {ex.Message}");
 
    }
 

    }

